# Cannot destructure property of 'undefined' as it is undefined react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to get the current time, so i used the new date function to get it, when i do so it is giving me an error saying time_cred undefined, when i remove date function the error goes. don't know what is happening

code.js

```
function Date({ time_cred }) {
const [date, setdate] = useState('');
const date_val = time_cred.slice(0, 10);
const time_val = time_cred.slice(11, 19);
var time = new Date();
console.log(time);
return <p id='forum_feed_upload_time'>{date_val}</p>;
}
```

Comment: how did you call the function "Date()"?. Also, its better to use a different name for it to avoid confusion of the class "Date"

Comment: It's probably a problem that your function name is `Date`, effectively shadowing the base type `Date` you try to use inside the function.

Comment: yes problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

'Date' is a reserved word, but you are overriding the Date function with function Date().

During the render of Date, you call Data again, creating on the one hand an infinity loop since Date calls itself, but also new Date() passes no props to itself, so the next time_cred is undefined.

Rename your Component to something else.